# Can I set two different values to an element using getElementById?

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

Can't I use getElementById twice in javascript file? I want to use it twice because, I want to set a default value to the element with that particular id and then on calling a function i need to change the default value. Can I do this? 
Have a look at my code:

```
function DefaultValue(){

    var default = 10.23
    var update = document.getElementById('idSpnRWA');
    update.innerHTML = default;

}
function setValue(){

    var set = 23.56;
    var finalUpdate = document.getElementById('idSpnRWA');
    finalUpdate.innerHTML = set;

}
```

I have given a very basic code to make you understand if this way is possible?

Comment: The problem (maybe) is you forgot to quote your string. Try `update.innerHTML = "10.23%";`

Comment: I have taken care of all those things, that's not the issue. The error here is that it is setting only the default value, the second value which i have given in the different function is not being set.

Comment: Can you show both your HTML *and* how `DefaultValue` / `setValue` are called? Better yet, produce a reproducible example within the question

Answer (score 1):

In short: yes, you can call `getElementById` as many times as you want.

Please note however, that `default` is a reserved word in JavaScript.
Also, you're forgetting to add `;` after each line.

Try this (note I renamed the `default` variable, and added `;` where needed.

**HTML**

```
<div id="idSpnRWA"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function DefaultValue() {
    var dflt = 10.23;
    var update = document.getElementById('idSpnRWA');
    update.innerHTML = dflt;
}

function setValue() {
    var set = 23.56;
    var finalUpdate = document.getElementById('idSpnRWA');
    finalUpdate.innerHTML = set;
}

DefaultValue();
setValue();
```

**Working Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/9e75vnm3/

Comment: But is not setting the value defined in the called function. It is only setting the default value. And it is not throwing up any error.

Comment: Use Firebug in Firefox. You should see `SyntaxError: expected expression, got ';'`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have the same HTML `id` attribute more than once on a page, but you can get anything as many times as you want, as long as it's not `undefined`. Of course, this means you can call `document.getElementById('idSpnRWA')` as many times as you want. You'll want to put percentages in quotes when assigning to `.innerHTML`, as `%` is the modulo operator. Better yet, use HTML entities. `Element.innerHTML = '10&#046;23&#037';`

Comment: No, because `%` is the modulo operator and your missing an expression because of that.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use `document.getElementById` many times.
But element with a specific id can be only once at your page.

Comment: Sure, just wrap 23.56% to quotes

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use getElementById as many time as you want. 
Problem in your code is that you are adding inner html as 10.23% which is not allowed. '%' is consider as a modulo operator. if you want to display in html than you have to concat it as string

```js
function DefaultValue() {
  var update = document.getElementById('idSpnRWA');
  update.innerHTML = 10.23 + '%';
}

function setValue() {
  var finalUpdate = document.getElementById('idSpnRWA');
  finalUpdate.innerHTML = 23.56 + '%';
}
DefaultValue();
```

```html
<div id='idSpnRWA'></div>
```

Comment: I have just given a value there to make you understand, but in my original code I am assigning it to variable. Don't worry about that

Comment: so now what problem you are facing? or what i have to worried about?

Comment: I found the solution. While assigning a variable, we should give finalUpdate.value but not finalUpdate.innerHTML. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

thank you so much for answering my question. I finally found the solution. it is, 
update.value= default;
finalUpdate.value = set;

innerHTML can't be used there. If i use .value, the code is actually working fine.